# Hash passwords in md5 with symfony 6.2

Tags: php, symfony, hash, md5

I'm currently working on a project that aims to move from a heavy Java application to a web application with Symfony.

The objective is to start from an existing database and not to modify it at all.

In this database, the password is hashed with md5.
After several weeks of troubles, I can't change the hash system of symfony to use md5.

I've done several tests, and with this line, the password is well hashed: hash('md5', $password);

Only, I would like the hashing to be done automatically, like in the basic symfony.
So I followed the symfony doc and tried to add these lines in the secutiry.yaml :
password_hashers:
app_hasher:
id: 'App\Security\Hasher\CustomVerySecureHasher'

Pointing therefore to the CustomVerySecureHasher file filled in as follows:

```
class CustomVerySecureHasher implements PasswordHasherInterface
{
    public function hash(string $plainPassword): string
    {
        // Check if the MD5 hash algorithm is supported
        if (!in_array('md5', hash_algos(), true)) {
            throw new Exception('MD5 is not supported by this system.');
        }

        // Hash the password using the MD5 algorithm
        return md5($plainPassword);
    }

    public function verify(string $hashedPassword, string $plainPassword): bool
    {
        // Compare the hashed password with the MD5 hashed plaintext password
        return $hashedPassword === md5($plainPassword);
    }

    public function needsRehash(string $hashedPassword): bool
    {
        // There is no need to rehash with MD5, as it is considered insecure
        return false;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work.
I tried multiple solutions, but none of them worked.

This is what my AppCustomAuthenticator class looks like (the one generated by the php bin/console make:auth command):

```
class AppCustomAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    public function __construct(private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('login', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

//        $password = $request->request->get('password', '');
//        $test = hash('md5', $password);
//        dd($test);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example:
        // return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

I have tested several times and I get my login and password from my form without any problem.
It is true that the hash stage is the problem.

Here is my login method in my security controller :

```
#[Route(path: '/', name: 'app_login')]
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
{
    // if ($this->getUser()) {
    //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
    // }

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
//        if ($lastUsername) {
//            dd($lastUsername);
//        }

    return $this->render('/security/login.html.twig', ['login' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
}
```

[EDIT] :
Here is the content of my security.yaml file:

```
security:
    password_hashers:
        App\Entity\Useraccount:
            id: 'App\Security\Hasher\CustomVerySecureHasher'
    providers:
        users_in_memory: { memory: null }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: users_in_memory
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator
access_control:

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

I'm using php 8.1 and symfony 6.2

Comment: Please don't use md5 for passwords. It's insecure and that's why Symfony does not support it out of the box. You should re-hash all passwords with strong algorithms that is intended for password hashing.

Comment: I understand your comment, but the question is not in that sense.
I know very well that md5 is not secure and the application will never go into production.
The goal is only to be able to use (in test) the postgresql database of a java project on this symfony project.
The goal of the project is not to change the existing database and therefore, for the time being, to keep the md5, even if this hash system is very outdated.

Comment: You’ve created `CustomVerySecureHasher` and registered it, but I’m not seeing you use it. If you are using a User entity, or something that implements PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface, I think (if I remember correctly), that you can replace `auto` with the ID, but otherwise you should be able to autowire using it: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/passwords.html#hashing-the-password

Comment: In fact, I have configured my config/package/security.yaml with this: security:
    password_hashers:
        app_hasher:
            id: 'App\Security\Hasher\CustomVerySecureHasher'
I thought it was enough for symfony to replace its default hash with mine (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/passwords.html#custom-password-hasher)
So it wouldn't be enough? Where is the "auto" that I have to replace with the id ? Are you talking about the one in the default security.yaml file?

Comment: I copied/pasted your latest security.yaml and it all works as expected.  My custom md5 hasher is properly called.  I suspect you have more going on in security.yaml that you are not showing.  Consider creating a new 6.2 app, run `make:user` then copy/paste/configure your hasher like the answer below shows.  That should give you a working base to compare against.  And needless to say (but I will say it anyways) if for some reason you are working in the development enviroment then a `cache:clear` might help.

Comment: And the way you describe the results of `security:hash-password` is very strange.  I can't imagine what would cause the utility to simply emit `"password"`.  It always puts out a key/value list for me.  There is also a PlaintextPasswordHasher which I suspect you might be using for your memory users.  But your posted security.yaml does not reflect that.

Comment: Thank you also for your reply. It helped me a lot!
I rarely use Symfony, I'm not very comfortable.
So I realized that I totally forgot to do the make:user command. In my case, I already had my entity, so I simply added the interface to my existing entity and implemented the missing methods.
Since then, the security:hash-password command works perfectly. It returns the hashed password, in md5, as I wanted.
The problem may not be the same anymore, but now, when I try to log in via my application's interface, it always tells me that the password is not good. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Symfony 6 changed some of the user interfaces including adding one specifically for passwords.  I'm guessing that is the difference between your legacy user and the one created by `make:user`.  As far as being unable to login, there are a bunch of duplicate questions on the same topic.  Probably need to do a bit of research.  Your Authenticator::onAuthenticationSuccess method will certainly need a tweak.

Comment: In fact, what I have a problem with is that the php bin/console security:hash-password command returns the correct hash based on the password provided, but on the other hand, my form on my GUI never goes through my custom hash (I have logged my class and I never go through it).
So I run the php bin/console debug:config security command and it returns the "hash-algorithm" value as sha512.
I suspect that my form is using sha512 instead of my custom hash.
I've looked everywhere on the internet, but I don't understand where my error could come from?
Could you give me a clue?

Comment: Your question seems to keep evolving and you seem reluctant to keep your posted code up to date.  I can only repeat an earlier suggestion and say to start over with a new project and just get the security working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have not seen one of these questions for awhile and Symfony 6 does make a few changes in the wiring.  Plus the documentation is quite verbose and not super clear.  You should be following [Password Hasher](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/passwords.html#configuring-a-password-hasher).

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        # Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
        App\Entity\User:
            id: 'App\Security\MyExtremelyInSecureHasher'
```

Test your wiring with:

```
$ bin/console security:hash-password password

Symfony Password Hash Utility
=============================

 --------------- ---------------------------------- 
  Key             Value                             
 --------------- ---------------------------------- 
  Hasher used     App\Security\MyExtremelyInSecureHasher            
  Password hash   5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99  
 --------------- ----------------------------------
```

There are variations on the configuration.  Might not need a custom hasher at all but it does not hurt to use one.  And of course once things are working then you setup an auto migration to a more secure hasher.

If you are still having trouble then update your question with the relevant contents of your security.yaml file.  Comments don't format well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I have just tried your proposal, unfortunately it does not seem to work yet.
I replaced the AppEntityUser with the name of my entity (Useraccount).
When I run the command to test the password hash, "Symfony Password Hash Utility" returns the non-hashed password only. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a custom class, just use the right algo and settings:

```
security:
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
            algorithm: md5
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 0
```

Check for password [`foo`](https://md5.gromweb.com/?string=foo):

```
 bin/console security:hash-password --empty-salt foo
```

Result:

```txt
Symfony Password Hash Utility
=============================

 --------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Key             Value                                                                
 --------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Hasher used     Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\MessageDigestPasswordHasher  
  Password hash   acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8
```